# Alsa does not enable recording

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

We have developed a linux based embedded board and copied the processor and audio chip from the evaluation board design, and of course alsa is used. On the evaluation board, audio playback and recording is working. On our board, only playback is working. 'arecord' is working, but no sound is actually received. We have no modifications in the driver source code. The device tree is configured as in the evaluation board.

I found out that the required enable bits in the audio controller are all not set, so it seems alsa is not configuring the device when recording. When i set the bits manually, recording does work, though with a wrong sample frequency.

I have gone through the alsamixer settings multiple times, and all values seem reasonable. So it is maybe just a small setting somewhere else which makes alsa behave this way, which i don't know of.

In the alsamixer settings, i am missing the input mute switch. It is defined in the source code, but does not appear in alsamixer. To check whether the input is muted in the mixer, i did a 'alsactl store' and looked at the generated file. It was not muted.

Do you have any ideas what else i could try? Or where in the source code is the location where the controller should be enabled?

The processor is an Atmel SAMA5D4, audio chip is WM8904.
Linux version 5.15.32
Audio driver(s):

sound/soc/atmel/atmel_wm8904.c
sound/soc/codecs/wm8904.c

amixer:

```
Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0
  Capabilities: volume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 63
  Front Left: 45 [71%] [-12.00dB] Playback [on]
  Front Right: 45 [71%] [-12.00dB] Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'Headphone ZC',0
  Capabilities: pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback [on]
  Front Right: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'Line Output',0
  Capabilities: volume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 63
  Front Left: 57 [90%] [0.00dB] Playback [on]
  Front Right: 57 [90%] [0.00dB] Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'Line Output ZC',0
  Capabilities: pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback [on]
  Front Right: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 31
  Front Left: Capture 5 [16%] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 5 [16%] [on]
Simple mixer control 'ADC 128x OSR',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'AIFOUTL Mux',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Left' 'Right'
  Item0: 'Left'
Simple mixer control 'AIFOUTR Mux',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Left' 'Right'
  Item0: 'Right'
Simple mixer control 'DAC Deemphasis',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'DAC OSRx2',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'DACL Mux',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Left' 'Right'
  Item0: 'Left'
Simple mixer control 'DACR Mux',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Left' 'Right'
  Item0: 'Right'
Simple mixer control 'DRC',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'DRC Path',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'ADC' 'DAC'
  Item0: 'ADC'
Simple mixer control 'Digital',0
  Capabilities: pvolume cvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 96 Capture 0 - 119
  Front Left: Playback 96 [100%] [0.00dB] Capture 96 [81%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 96 [100%] [0.00dB] Capture 96 [81%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Digital Playback Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Mono: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Digital Sidetone',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 15
  Front Left: 0 [0%] [-36.00dB]
  Front Right: 0 [0%] [-36.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'EQ',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'EQ1',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 24
  Mono: 12 [50%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'EQ2',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 24
  Mono: 12 [50%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'EQ3',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 24
  Mono: 12 [50%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'EQ4',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 24
  Mono: 12 [50%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'EQ5',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 24
  Mono: 12 [50%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'HPL Mux',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'DAC' 'Bypass'
  Item0: 'DAC'
Simple mixer control 'HPR Mux',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'DAC' 'Bypass'
  Item0: 'DAC'
Simple mixer control 'High Pass Filter',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'High Pass Filter Mode',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Hi-fi' 'Voice 1' 'Voice 2' 'Voice 3'
  Item0: 'Hi-fi'
Simple mixer control 'LINEL Mux',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'DAC' 'Bypass'
  Item0: 'DAC'
Simple mixer control 'LINER Mux',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'DAC' 'Bypass'
  Item0: 'DAC'
Simple mixer control 'Left Capture Inverting Mux',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'IN1L' 'IN2L' 'IN3L'
  Item0: 'IN1L'
Simple mixer control 'Left Capture Mode',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Single-Ended' 'Differential Line' 'Differential Mic'
  Item0: 'Single-Ended'
Simple mixer control 'Left Capture Mux',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'IN1L' 'IN2L' 'IN3L'
  Item0: 'IN2L'
Simple mixer control 'Left Sidetone',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'None' 'Left' 'Right'
  Item0: 'None'
Simple mixer control 'Right Capture Inverting Mux',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'IN1R' 'IN2R' 'IN3R'
  Item0: 'IN1R'
Simple mixer control 'Right Capture Mode',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Single-Ended' 'Differential Line' 'Differential Mic'
  Item0: 'Single-Ended'
Simple mixer control 'Right Capture Mux',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'IN1R' 'IN2R' 'IN3R'
  Item0: 'IN2R'
Simple mixer control 'Right Sidetone',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'None' 'Left' 'Right'
  Item0: 'None'
```

/var/lib/alsa/asound.state:

```
state.SAMA5D4GGARD {
        control.1 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'EQ1 Volume'
                value 12
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type INTEGER
                        count 1
                        range '0 - 24'
                        dbmin -1200
                        dbmax 1200
                        dbvalue.0 0
                }
        }
        control.2 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'EQ2 Volume'
                value 12
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type INTEGER
                        count 1
                        range '0 - 24'
                        dbmin -1200
                        dbmax 1200
                        dbvalue.0 0
                }
        }
        control.3 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'EQ3 Volume'
                value 12
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type INTEGER
                        count 1
                        range '0 - 24'
                        dbmin -1200
                        dbmax 1200
                        dbvalue.0 0
                }
        }
        control.4 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'EQ4 Volume'
                value 12
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type INTEGER
                        count 1
                        range '0 - 24'
                        dbmin -1200
                        dbmax 1200
                        dbvalue.0 0
                }
        }
        control.5 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'EQ5 Volume'
                value 12
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type INTEGER
                        count 1
                        range '0 - 24'
                        dbmin -1200
                        dbmax 1200
                        dbvalue.0 0
                }
        }
        control.6 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'Digital Capture Volume'
                value.0 96
                value.1 96
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type INTEGER
                        count 2
                        range '0 - 119'
                        dbmin -9999999
                        dbmax 1725
                        dbvalue.0 0
                        dbvalue.1 0
                }
        }
        control.7 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'Capture Volume'
                value.0 5
                value.1 5
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type INTEGER
                        count 2
                        range '0 - 31'
                }
        }
        control.8 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'Capture Switch'
                value.0 true
                value.1 true
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type BOOLEAN
                        count 2
                }
        }
        control.9 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'High Pass Filter Switch'
                value true
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type BOOLEAN
                        count 1
                }
        }
        control.10 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'High Pass Filter Mode'
                value Hi-fi
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type ENUMERATED
                        count 1
                        item.0 Hi-fi
                        item.1 'Voice 1'
                        item.2 'Voice 2'
                        item.3 'Voice 3'
                }
        }
        control.11 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'ADC 128x OSR Switch'
                value true
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type BOOLEAN
                        count 1
                }
        }
        control.12 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'Digital Playback Boost Volume'
                value 0
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type INTEGER
                        count 1
                        range '0 - 3'
                        dbmin 0
                        dbmax 1800
                        dbvalue.0 0
                }
        }
        control.13 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'Digital Playback Volume'
                value.0 96
                value.1 96
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type INTEGER
                        count 2
                        range '0 - 96'
                        dbmin -9999999
                        dbmax 0
                        dbvalue.0 0
                        dbvalue.1 0
                }
        }
        control.14 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'Headphone Volume'
                value.0 45
                value.1 45
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type INTEGER
                        count 2
                        range '0 - 63'
                        dbmin -5700
                        dbmax 600
                        dbvalue.0 -1200
                        dbvalue.1 -1200
                }
        }
        control.15 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'Headphone Switch'
                value.0 true
                value.1 true
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type BOOLEAN
                        count 2
                }
        }
        control.16 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'Headphone ZC Switch'
                value.0 true
                value.1 true
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type BOOLEAN
                        count 2
                }
        }
        control.17 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'Line Output Volume'
                value.0 57
                value.1 57
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type INTEGER
                        count 2
                        range '0 - 63'
                        dbmin -5700
                        dbmax 600
                        dbvalue.0 0
                        dbvalue.1 0
                }
        }
        control.18 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'Line Output Switch'
                value.0 true
                value.1 true
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type BOOLEAN
                        count 2
                }
        }
        control.19 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'Line Output ZC Switch'
                value.0 true
                value.1 true
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type BOOLEAN
                        count 2
                }
        }
        control.20 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'EQ Switch'
                value false
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type BOOLEAN
                        count 1
                }
        }
        control.21 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'DRC Switch'
                value false
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type BOOLEAN
                        count 1
                }
        }
        control.22 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'DRC Path'
                value ADC
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type ENUMERATED
                        count 1
                        item.0 ADC
                        item.1 DAC
                }
        }
        control.23 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'DAC OSRx2 Switch'
                value false
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type BOOLEAN
                        count 1
                }
        }
        control.24 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'DAC Deemphasis Switch'
                value false
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type BOOLEAN
                        count 1
                }
        }
        control.25 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'Digital Sidetone Volume'
                value.0 0
                value.1 0
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type INTEGER
                        count 2
                        range '0 - 15'
                        dbmin -3600
                        dbmax 900
                        dbvalue.0 -3600
                        dbvalue.1 -3600
                }
        }
        control.26 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'Left Capture Mux'
                value IN2L
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type ENUMERATED
                        count 1
                        item.0 IN1L
                        item.1 IN2L
                        item.2 IN3L
                }
        }
        control.27 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'Left Capture Inverting Mux'
                value IN1L
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type ENUMERATED
                        count 1
                        item.0 IN1L
                        item.1 IN2L
                        item.2 IN3L
                }
        }
        control.28 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'Left Capture Mode'
                value Single-Ended
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type ENUMERATED
                        count 1
                        item.0 Single-Ended
                        item.1 'Differential Line'
                        item.2 'Differential Mic'
                }
        }
        control.29 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'Right Capture Mux'
                value IN2R
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type ENUMERATED
                        count 1
                        item.0 IN1R
                        item.1 IN2R
                        item.2 IN3R
                }
        }
        control.30 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'Right Capture Inverting Mux'
                value IN1R
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type ENUMERATED
                        count 1
                        item.0 IN1R
                        item.1 IN2R
                        item.2 IN3R
                }
        }
        control.31 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'Right Capture Mode'
                value Single-Ended
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type ENUMERATED
                        count 1
                        item.0 Single-Ended
                        item.1 'Differential Line'
                        item.2 'Differential Mic'
                }
        }
        control.32 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'AIFOUTL Mux'
                value Left
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type ENUMERATED
                        count 1
                        item.0 Left
                        item.1 Right
                }
        }
        control.33 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'AIFOUTR Mux'
                value Right
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type ENUMERATED
                        count 1
                        item.0 Left
                        item.1 Right
                }
        }
        control.34 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'DACL Mux'
                value Left
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type ENUMERATED
                        count 1
                        item.0 Left
                        item.1 Right
                }
        }
        control.35 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'DACR Mux'
                value Right
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type ENUMERATED
                        count 1
                        item.0 Left
                        item.1 Right
                }
        }
        control.36 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'Left Sidetone'
                value None
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type ENUMERATED
                        count 1
                        item.0 None
                        item.1 Left
                        item.2 Right
                }
        }
        control.37 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'Right Sidetone'
                value None
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type ENUMERATED
                        count 1
                        item.0 None
                        item.1 Left
                        item.2 Right
                }
        }
        control.38 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'HPL Mux'
                value DAC
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type ENUMERATED
                        count 1
                        item.0 DAC
                        item.1 Bypass
                }
        }
        control.39 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'HPR Mux'
                value DAC
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type ENUMERATED
                        count 1
                        item.0 DAC
                        item.1 Bypass
                }
        }
        control.40 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'LINEL Mux'
                value DAC
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type ENUMERATED
                        count 1
                        item.0 DAC
                        item.1 Bypass
                }
        }
        control.41 {
                iface MIXER
                name 'LINER Mux'
                value DAC
                comment {
                        access 'read write'
                        type ENUMERATED
                        count 1
                        item.0 DAC
                        item.1 Bypass
                }
        }
}
```